# Path of <form> elements in onsubmit event listener

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-objects

I managed to find the event element's path to change the color of a `<form>` input field's `<label>` from a event listener.Now I want to do the same from an `onsubmit` handler, but I can't figure out the correct path:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <label id="labelForInput" for="inputField">LABEL</label>
  <input id="inputField">
  <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>

<script>
  document.getElementById("inputField").addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

  function clickHandler(event) {
      // onClick on input element, the label's color changes to red:
      event.srcElement.labels[0].style.color='red';
  }

  document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener( "submit", {return submitHandler} );

  function submitHandler(event) {
      // What's the path to change the label's color to 'green' upon click on submit button?
      // **???** .style.color='`green';
      return false;
  }
</script>
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, my question was a bit oversimplyfied. **I don't know the labels ids and names** in the onsubmit handler, only the input field's names, thus I can't use outright `getElementById`. Actually, in the paticular case, the labels don't have ids nor names defined, but they are bound to their input fields by 'for='. I'm looping over an array containing the input field names and I want to change a label's color upon a condition:

```
const fieldNames=['form_name','form_email','form_message'];
const fieldConds=[true, false, true];

function submitHandler(event) {
  fieldConds.forEach( (value, idx) => { 
            if (!value) { ... CHANGE COLOR ... }
}
```

So, I think what I'm looking for is something like `callingFormObject.inputFields[].label.style.color` , like I used in clickHandler. But in onsubmit, the event object seems to only contains the string representing the form, no property fields.

Comment: Why would the <label> be referenced in that event? The event says that the <form> is being submitted. The <label> is for the <input type=text>, there is no other link than <form> is an ancestor of that <label>, but the <label> didn't participate at all in the form submission. So, is this <label> the only one that descends from the <form>? In that case it's just `const label = event.currentTarget.querySelector("label")`. But if one day you decide to add another unrelated <label> in there, your code may start to fail.

Comment: regarding the edit of the post: you can add to the querySelector also attributes. So in particular the input with a certain name you would get as 
`myForm.querySelector("input[name='form_name']")` . For the label it depends how exactly it lies in the dom. You could either go from the input-Element via `inputField.previousElementSibling()` to the label (if your sketched dom-structure is true). Or you use `labels = myForm.querySelectorAll("label")` and then filter them via `[].filter.call(labels, l => l.getAttribute('for') == input.id)`

Comment: @Sebastian Last statement is pretty complex, but that's the correct answer.

Comment: @jamacoe great, good to hear. I've posted it now as an answer with a little more explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the edit of the original post:

One can add to the querySelector also attributes. So in particular the input with a certain name can be obtained as `myForm.querySelector("input[name='form_name']")`. To find the corresponding labels one can first get the list of all labels with `querySelectorAll()` yielding a `NodeList` and then filter them to obtain the one that refers to the current input-field in its `for`-attribute. `NodeList` doesn't have its own `filter()`-method, so one has to borrow it from the `Array.prototype` or simply from an empty array `[]` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for the filter-method and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) for the borrowing via `call` syntax):

```
function submitHandler(event) {
fieldConds.forEach( (value, idx) => { 
   if (!value) {
      const input = myForm.querySelector(`input[name=${fieldNames[idx]}]`);
      const labels = myForm.querySelectorAll("label");
      const labelForInput = [].filter.call(labels, l => l.getAttribute('for') == input.id)[0]; // filter should only leave a single entry in the resulting array
      labelForInput.style.color = "green"; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Good. Even though labelForInput only has a legth of 1 (one element), I still had to index labelForInput[0].style.color = "green"; without it yields "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'color')" in Chrome Devtools.

Comment: @jamacoe indeed I forgot about `[0]` in my first comment, but in this answer the `[0]` is already at the very end of the line : )

Answer (score 2):

```js
    document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener( "submit", submitHandler);

  function submitHandler(event) {
      //so it doesnt refresh your page
      event.preventDefault()
      //grab form element
      const formEl = event.currentTarget
      //grab label element
      const label = formEl.querySelector("#labelForInput")
      label.style.color = "green"
      return false;
  }
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <label id="labelForInput" for="inputField">LABEL</label>
  <input id="inputField">
  <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Try the following:

```
  function submitHandler(event) {
      //so it doesnt refresh your page
      event.preventDefault()
      //grab form element
      const formEl = event.currentTarget
      //grab label element
      const label = formEl.querySelector("#labelForInput")
      label.style.color = "green"
      /*or you can select all labels
      const labels =  formEl.querySelectorAll("label")
      labels[0].style.color = "green"
      */
      return false;
  }
```

Comment: looks good, but can't test it now, no computer 'till Sunday. The .currentTarget and querySelector look promising. Thank you for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly set the label's color to green using its ID in your handler function:

```
document.getElementById("labelForInput").style.color = "green";
```